# Моделирование ситуации в задаче на теорию вероятности

Tags: c++, теория-вероятностей, вычислительный-эксперимент

У меня было задание написать алгоритм решения вот такой задачи: если Вадим играет с Денисом в шахматы белыми, то он выигрывает у Дениса с вероятностью 0,7. Если Вадим играет чёрными, то он выигрывает с вероятностью 0,6. Вадим и Денис играют две партии, причём во второй партии меняют цвет фигур.
Найдите вероятность того, что Вадим выиграет оба раза.

Я написал следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); // русский язык
    int n = rand() % 2 + 1; // случайное 1 или 2
    // 1 - начинают белые, 2 - черные
    if (n == 1)
        cout << "Начали с белых, вероятность " << 0.7 * 0.6 << endl;
    else
        cout << "Начали с черных, вероятность " << 0.6 * 0.7 << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Но нужно было использовать моделирование ситуации, как мне его добавить в код?

Comment: Выполните очень много раз (сто тысяч, например) цикл, в котором сгенерируйте условие победы случайным образом с заданной вероятностью и посмотрите долю нужных исходов

Comment: вы неправильно поняли задачу - ее надо решить проведя многочисленные эксперименты, а не просто написать `std::cout << 0,42`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, самая простая именно модель (не просто перемножение 0.6 и 0.7) - вот:

```
default_random_engine rnd(random_device{}());

bool ok()
{
    bool win[2] = {};
    uniform_int_distribution<>d(0,1);
    uniform_real_distribution<>r(0.0,1.0);

    if (d(rnd))
    {
        win[0] = r(rnd) < 0.7;
        win[1] = r(rnd) < 0.6;
    }
    else
    {
        win[1] = r(rnd) < 0.7;
        win[0] = r(rnd) < 0.6;
    }
    return win[0] && win[1];
}


int main()
{
    int wins = 0, total = 1000000;
    for(int i = 0; i < total; ++i)
        if (ok()) wins++;
    cout << double(wins)/total << endl;
}
```

Т.е. реально моделируем, какая игра первая, какая вторая, победы в них...

Ну, а [тут](https://ideone.com/gMjOnu) - результат.